# Mixing models using principal component scores

Tags: pca, biostatistics

For my honors thesis, I am trying to determine what coyotes eat using isotope statistical mixing models. They can eat wild animals (deer, rabbits, etc.) or domestic animals (sheep, cattle, etc.). I have 5 isotope values each (carbon, nitrogen, oxygen, sulfur, hydrogen) for 10 different wild animals and 10 different domestic animals, plus the coyotes.

When I did an exploratory PCA, the wild and domestic animals end up on different ends of the first principal component axis, suggesting a chemical isotope difference between them. All 5 isotopes combine to make a kind of "signature" that says wild or domestic.

My main question is: can I use the average PC1 scores for wild/domestic as end members in a simple linear mixing model? For example, wild average about -1, domestic average about 2. So if a coyote had a PC1 score of -1, I predict a 100% wild diet. A PC1 score of 0.5, and a 50% wild/50% domestic diet. Is this "allowed"? Related questions:
(1) What if it gets a score not in between the 2 end members?
(2) If I should use an R mixing model program like MixSIAR instead, can you recommend a good one?